# ReplaceAll not working

Tags: android, replaceall

I'm using google volley to retrieve source code from website. Some looping was done to capture the value in the code. I've successfully captured the data I wanted, but error was shown: NumberFormatException: Invalid float: "2,459.00"

My intention was to store the value after the class=ListPrice>
Sample:
RM 2,899.00

The example value of the source code I wanted to save is "RM2,459.00 "

Below is the code I've written:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lazada_result);
    lelongResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lelong_result);

    RequestQueue lelong = MyVolley.getRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest myLel = new StringRequest(
            Method.GET,
            "http://list.lelong.com.my/Auc/List/List.asp?DA=A&TheKeyword=iphone&x=0&y=0&CategoryID=&PriceLBound=&PriceUBound=",
            RetrieveLelong(), createMyReqErrorListener());
    lelong.add(myLel);

}

private Response.Listener<String> RetrieveLelong() {
    return new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            ArrayList<Float> integers = new ArrayList<>();
            String to = "class=ListPrice>";
            String remainingText = response;
            String showP = "";
            while (remainingText.indexOf(to) >= 0) {
                String tokenString = remainingText.substring(remainingText
                        .indexOf(to) + to.length());
                String priceString = tokenString.substring(0,
                        tokenString.indexOf("<"));
                float price = Float.parseFloat(priceString.replaceAll("[^\\d,]+", "").trim());                  
                integers.add((price / 100));
                remainingText = tokenString;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < integers.size(); i++) {
                String test1 = Float.toString(integers.get(i));
                showP += test1 + "\n";
            }
            lelongResult.setText(showP);
        }
    };
}
```

The problem was as below:

I've tried all sort of replaceAll(),

1)replaceAll("[^\d,]+","") result:2,89900

replace all character except digits and comma works.

2)replaceAll("[^\d]+","") result:Invalid int""

replace all character include comma and dot ,not working

3)replaceAll("[^\d.]+,"") result:Invalid int""

replace all character exclude digits and dot, not working

From the experiment 2&3 coding above,I've noticed that if the comma were removed,i cant parseFloat as the value received by it is: "".NumberFormatException:Invalid Float:"" shown.

From the experiment 1,NumberFormatException:Invalid Float "2,45900" is showned.

The problem was replacing comma ,the code will not work but with the presence of comma ,the value cannot be stored into string

Comment: show the code - how you used replaceAll(",", "")?

Comment: Show some more code, where you used this "price" variable.

Answer (score 0):

use `replaceAll(Pattern.quote(","), "");

**EDIT**

if you want only numbers then use this

String s1=   s.replaceAll("\D+","");

Comment: ,the error still remains.
NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "2,459.00"

Comment: check the updated question i posted,i found a problem on the comma replacement

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
float price = Float.parseFloat(priceString.replaceAll("RM", "").trim());
```

Comment: the RM is the currency...i'm retrieving source code from an online shopping website .

Comment: @CodeX,I've tried ur code,yet the error remains the same.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "2,459.00"

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse the number by specifying the Locale.

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.KOREAN);
Number number = format.parse(priceString.replaceAll("RM", ""));
double d = number.doubleValue();
```

I'm just guessing the locale, don't know what you should use, depends on country

Comment: i've updated the question,seem like the problem is with the comma replacement. :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that in your code:

```
priceString.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(","), "");
float price = Float.parseFloat(priceString.replaceAll("\\D+\\s+", "").trim());
```

You are replacing coma but not storing the value!
you have to do:

```
priceString = priceString.replaceAll(",", "");
float price = Float.parseFloat(priceString.replaceAll("\\D+\\s+", "").trim());
```

I'm not sure of the pattern "\D+\s" because if you remove the coma you don't need to replace anything else (except "RM" that i assume you already removed)

Update: set locale and parse a number:

```
   NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.KOREAN); 
Number number = format.parse(priceString.replaceAll("RM", "")); 
double d = number.doubleValue();
```

Comment: I've try changing these:
replaceAll("[^\d,]+","") result:2,899.00

replaceAll("[^\d]+","") result:Invalid int""

replaceAll("[^\d.]+,"") result:Invalid int""

yet i cant get the result...

Comment: please clarify, the question and the further modification can't help to understand what you have, what you do and what you want...

Comment: @N Dorigatti, sorry for confusing and messy question. I've tried to update my question with clearer explanation. Thanks.

Comment: so as far as i understand, you receive "RM2,899.00" as a string and you want to store the value 2899.00 in your database (I'm using "." as decimal separator), right?
if so, you can do replaceAll("RM","") to remove the alphanumeric characters, then the replaceAll(",","") to remove the coma and have the number 2899.00 as string (you can do also a trim() to remove spaces);
At this point you can parse the string as a float or double, but you should set a Locale, because I don't know your country defaults! ____ If this does not answer your question, please write input and desired output as comment

Comment: @N Dorigatti, thanks for such details explanation. How can I set the locale so that the system would recognize?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it one by one

```
 priceString=priceString.replaceAll("\\D", "");

 priceString=priceString.replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

now

```
 priceString=priceString.trim();
 float price = Float.parseFloat(priceString);
```

Comment: had change according to ur code yet the Invalid float show:"",been testing lot's of different regexr,found a problem regarding the comma...whenever the comma is being replaced or removed,the error show,else no prob.